# how to pass HashMap between two methods

Tags: java

I have two methods: one that creates the HashMap and second that should get the HashMap from the first one. Can someone please help how to do it?

code:

```
public HashMap<Object, Integer> createHash(boolean include){


        HashMap<Object, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();

        if(!include){
            do some stuff
        }
        return newMap;
}


public ArrayList<String> getHash(boolean include){  

        HashMap<Object, Integer> newMap = new newMap.createHash(); //getting error or below

        HashMap<Object, Integer> newMap  = new createHash();//error too

            //here I would like to use newMap

        return something;
}
```

EDIT: both methods are within the same class

Comment: you need to pass in a boolean to the createhash method, as per the method signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createHash` method is a non-static function that resides on some class, **which you haven't shown us**.  The correct syntax to invoke this method, as it's currently defined is:

```
   //create an instance
   MyFoo foo = new Foo(); // instance of class you haven't shown us
   //invoke the createHash method on the foo instance...
   Map<Object, Integer> newMap = foo.createHash(true);
```

or

if you're already on an instance of `MyFoo`, just call the method directly:

```
   Map<Object, Integer> newMap = createHash(true);
```

The syntax you are using:

```
 new createHash();
```

will not compile.  The new keyword is only appropriate for constructors.

Comment: The TS says the two methodes are in the same class. Therefore it would not be nessecarry to do the "MyFoo foo = new MyFoo(); thing.

Comment: Sure, i guess that was an update.  In such a case, just invoke the createHash method directly.

Comment: If you want to use use contructor and call a method in the same line you could do: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
Map<Object, Integer> myMap = (new MyFoo()).getSomething();